# WebdriverIO fails to execute a few lines of client side JS

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

I'm trying to run the following snippet using [WebdriverIO](https://webdriver.io):

```
browser.executeScript(
  `var element = document.createElement('a');
   element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent('./images/file.txt'));
   element.setAttribute('download', 'file.txt');
   element.style.display = 'none';
   document.body.appendChild(element);
   element.click();`
);
```

I get the following error:

> [0-0] SyntaxError in "Name of the suite" Unexpected identifier

**Note:** When I run the JS part in the browser console, it works as intended.

Comment: Hi Artem, I am not sure you are following the syntax of `browser.executeScript` .. the first argument of it takes a `string`. https://webdriver.io/docs/api/webdriver.html#executescript

Answer (score 0):

The solution:  error was caused by
 browser.pause();
line of code. So avoid using browser.pause() with browser.execute in one test suite

Comment: This makes no sense. First of all, I don't see any `browser.pause();` inside the question. Secondly, it's an invalid statement, as you **CAN** use `pause()` & `execute()` inside the same test file. WDIO handles the Promise queue behind the scenes for you.